# SPI WRITE for DRV8889

Tags: stm32, spi

I am **not able to write** to the registers of DRV8889 using SPI, but I am able to read them, don't know where I am going wrong.
I am using an STM32G431C8T6. I have gone through the datasheet thoroughly and have no clue what the issue might be.

Input and Output Data format for SPI on DRV8889 registers

[image: data format for SPI]
<sup>Source: [DRV8889 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8889-q1.pdf)</sup>

Output to my code trying to write and read from a register 0x07:-

[image]

SPI write code:-
[image]

```c
    int main(void)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

      /* USER CODE END 1 */

      /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

      /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
      HAL_Init();

      /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

      /* USER CODE END Init */

      /* Configure the system clock */
      SystemClock_Config();

      /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

      /* USER CODE END SysInit */

      /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
      MX_GPIO_Init();
      MX_SPI2_Init();
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

        //BYTE1=(addr<<1) |0x40; //read the register


        rx_buffer1[0] = 0;
        rx_buffer1[1] = 0;
        rx_buffer1_1[0] = 0;
        rx_buffer1_1[1] = 0;
        spi_error = 0;
        count=0;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);//nSLEEP
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);//NSS B
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);//NSS A
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//ENABLE PIN ON



        addr=0x07;
        BYTE1=addr<<1; //WRITE the register
        //BYTE1=(addr<<1) |0x40; //read the register
        BYTE2=0x05;   //1000b = 50% control register1 address = 0x03
        tx_buffer1[0] = BYTE2;
        tx_buffer1[1] = BYTE1;
        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//NSS A
        if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2,(uint8_t*)tx_buffer1,(uint8_t*)rx_buffer1,2,100)!= HAL_OK){
                      spi_error++;
                      Error_Handler();
                      }

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);//NSS A
        HAL_Delay(500);


      /* USER CODE END 2 */

      /* Infinite loop */
      /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
      while (1)
      {
       //addr=0x03;
       BYTE1_1=(addr<<1) |0x40; //read the register
       //BYTE1_1=0X07;
       BYTE2_1=0x0;
       tx_buffer1_1[1] = BYTE1_1;
       tx_buffer1_1[0] = BYTE2_1;

       HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//NSS A
       if(HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi2,(uint8_t*)tx_buffer1_1,(uint8_t*)rx_buffer1_1,2,HAL_TIMEOUT)!= HAL_OK)
       {
        spi_error++;
        Error_Handler();
       }
       HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);//NSS A
       HAL_Delay(500);


    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
    }
    /* USER CODE END 3 */
    }
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code. Its really easy to add it into your question, please do so.

Comment: I have added the code now. I didn't add it before cause I am able to read from the registers so in all probability there is nothing that needs to be changed in the code cause when writing to a register you only change the data being sent

Answer (score 1):

The transaction should look as follows:

[image]

<sup>Source: [DRV8889 Datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8889-q1.pdf)</sup>

Your source code doesn't reflect that.

---

*Your comment:*

> Okay I understand where you are coming from but your solution is wrong. Actually the very first time even I sent the data in the way you have suggested but realised it doesn't work and shifted to the one provided in question. If you carefully look at the printing of live variables you can see that not only read works perfectly but while writing too I get the current value of the register. The problem is after write operation the data doesn't change in the register

Maybe the SPI driver is configured to switch the two bytes. Look at the source code of `MX_SPI2_Init()`. Perhaps that'll clear things up.

If you hooked up a scope or digital analyzer, you'll see that the bytes are sent and received in the order described by the datasheet.

It's quite obvious that the DRV8889 first needs to *know* the address of the register (**A1**), before it could respond with the actual data of that register (**R1**).

The response of the DRV8889 always starts with **S1** (status flags), because for this it doesn't have to know the address. The next byte is **R1**, which depends on the address defined in **A1**.

[image]

Comment: Okay I understand where you are coming from but your solution is wrong.
Actually the very first time even I sent the data in the way you have suggested but realised it doesn't work and shifted to the one provided in question.

If you carefully look at the printing of live variables you can see that not only read works perfectly but while writing too I get the current value of the register.
The problem is after write operation the data doesn't change in the register